# Java Script factorial function doesn't give expected results

Tags: javascript, loops, math

I am new to javascript. My code is working OK with some numbers, but Factorial(5) gives me 121 instead of 120.

```
function factorialize(num) {
    var factorial=0;
    var x=0;

    for(factorial=1; factorial<=num; factorial++) {
        for(x=1; x<=num; x++) {
           factorial*= x;
        }
    } 

    return factorial;
}

factorialize(5);
```

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) for more about asking high-quality questions.  In this situation, check your algorithm - a factorial only needs one loop to compute, not two (`factorial` and `x` in your code).

Answer (score 1):

For some reason you are trying to implement factorial with two loops. One of those loops has `factorial++` on it, which will affect your answers.

Just remove the unneeded outer loop and you're fine.

Answer (score 0):

As you know 5! = 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5.

Here is a simple way to implement it in JS.

```
function factorialize(n) {    

    result = 1;
    for (i = 1; i<=n; i++) {
        result *= i;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a recursive approach:

```
var factorial = function(number) {
  if (number <= 0) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return number * factorial(number - 1);
  }
};
```

Or, if you want to be nice and short, simply use ternary:

```
var newFactorial = function(number) {
  return number <= 0 ? 1 : number * factorial(number - 1);
};
```